# Turtle attribute not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Complete newbie here. Can I know why I got error message (NameError: name 'width' is not defined) when I run this code? Thanks :)

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *

root = Tk()
T = Text(root, root.title("Controls"), height=8, width=60)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, """Right arrow key = move forward\nLeft arrow key = move 
backward\nr = turn right\nl = turn left\n
u = pen up\nd = pen down\nh = go home\nc = clear""")


def main():
    width(2)
    speed(0)
    pencolor("blue")
    onkey(up, "u")
    onkey(down, "d")
    onkey(clear, "c")
    onkey(home, "h")
    onkey(lambda: forward(5), "right")
    onkey(lambda: back(5), "left")
    onkey(lambda: left(5), "l")
    onkey(lambda: right(5), "r")
    listen()
    return "Done!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
msg = main()
print(msg)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got error message (NameError: name 'width' is not defined) when I
>   run this code

When I ran this code, I got the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "right"

This code is a mess, specifically:

- It puts up two windows by combining turtle and tkinter in an uncontrolled fashion.  When turtle is standalone, we use `Turtle` and `Screen`, but when embedded in tkinter, we use `RawTurtle` and `TurtleScreen`.  Rather than have the second window come up as a side effect of ignoring the rules, you really should have control over the creation of that window.
- This code appears to set the title of the root window as a side effect of passing `None` as the `XView` argument to `Text()`:

  T = Text(root, root.title("Controls"), height=8, width=60)
- You're using the wrong key names for the arrows -- they should be `'Left'` and `'Right`' for turtle's `onkey()` function, not `'left'` and `'right'`.

Here's my understanding of how this type of program should be constructucted:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, ScrolledCanvas, TurtleScreen

root = tk.Tk()

instructions = tk.Toplevel()
instructions.title("Controls")

text = tk.Text(instructions, height=8, width=60)
text.pack()
text.insert(tk.END, """Right arrow key = move forward\nLeft arrow key = move
backward\nr = turn right\nl = turn left\n
u = pen up\nd = pen down\nh = go home\nc = clear""")

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen, 'turtle')
turtle.pencolor('blue')
turtle.width(2)

screen.onkey(turtle.penup, "u")
screen.onkey(turtle.pendown, "d")
screen.onkey(turtle.clear, "c")
screen.onkey(turtle.home, "h")

screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.forward(5), "Right")
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.backward(5), "Left")
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.left(5), "l")
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.right(5), "r")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```